# Why the Hypergeometric distribution formula ignores order?

Tags: probability

> D red balls, N-D black balls (total is N). We draw $n$ balls without replacement. Let X be the number of red balls. Compute the distribution of X.

$$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{D}{k}k!\binom{N-D}{n-k}(n-k)!}{\binom{N}{n}n!}$$

Each permutation is a different event so why we ignore a lot of them in our count?

Comment: Because by definition all that we care about is the number of red balls in the draw.

Comment: but we need to count down all the events which have k red balls. the number of events will affect the probability. so why you are ignoring all the permutations?

Comment: You're not really ignoring them. Think about the binomial distribution: why is it more likely that a fair coin will come up heads twice in four flips rather than once? It is not because the individual permutations with two heads are actually more likely, it is because there are more of them. The situation is basically the same in the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: If you want to count them as permutations, then you must fix up the numerator of your formula since a permutation of $n$ balls is more than just the separate orderings of the blacks and the reds -- you must specify how they interleave. Of course this ends up replacing the two factorials in your numerator with a single $n!$, which gives you the original formula after cancelling the $n!$. In other words, its easier to directly count the samples as combinations since the combinations are equally likely and replacing them by permutations just multiplies every count by exactly $n!$.

Comment: @Ned I got you. Thanks. Does it mean that I can ignore the order in any calculation if I ignore it in each side of the fraction?

Comment: If you are picking samples without replacement AND the event you want does not refer to the order in which sample elements were picked, then combinations are easier because the numbers are smaller. On the other hand, with identical trials, like rolling three dice, it is easier to model the results as ordered triples since those are equally likely while combinations are not ( as unordered triples, {1,3,4}. Is more likely than {2,2,5}, for example )